# If $f\ge0$ and $ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)^kdx$ does not depend on $k\geq 1$ then $f=\mathbf 1_A$ almost everywhere, for some measurable subset $A$ of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> If $ \int_{0}^{1} (f(x))^k dx= C$ for all $k\geq 1$, then there exists a measurable subset A of [0,1] where $f(x)=1_{A}(x)$ for almost every x

Note that $ f:[0,1] -> R^{+}$

I am stuck on this problem. Here is what I have done so far..
We know $\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx = \int_{0}^{1} f^2(x) dx $ which implies $\int (f-f^2) dx= 0$ which implies $f(x)-f^2(x)= 0$ almost everywhere on [0,1], which implies $f(x)(1-f(x))=0$ a.e. on [0,1] hence f(x)= 0 or 1 for a.e. x on [0,1].

Where do I go from here? Is this correct so far? How do I know that the set of points where $f(x)=1$,call it A, will be measurable necessarily? Also how do I use the other powers of f? I feel I am missing something.

Comment: What values may $f$ take?

Comment: Oh sorry I will edit, $ f:[0,1] -> R^{+}$

Comment: "$\int (f-f^2) dx= 0$ which implies $f(x)-f^2(x)= 0$ almost everywhere on [0,1]" For this implication to hold, you would need to know that $f-f^2$ has almost everywhere constant sign, for example because $0\le f\le1$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Ahh thanks Did, thats correct.  Any ideas on how to proceed then?

Comment: Yes: first show that the measure of $\{f>1\}$ is zero. To do so, assume that the measure of $\{f\geqslant t\}$ is not zero, for some $t>1$, and study the asymptotics of $\int_0^1f^k$ when $k\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You first have to show that $f$ a.e. takes values in $[0,1]$ only. To see this define for $n\geq 1$ the set  $A_n=\{f\geq 1+\frac{1}{n}\}$. Then for any $k$ we have $C=\int_0^1 f^k dx \geq |A_n| (1+\frac{1}{n})^k$ which implies $|A_n|=0$. So the set $\{f>1\}=\cup_n A_n$ has zero measure. And you may proceed as before.

Comment: Thank you so much to the two of you!

Comment: Just to make sure, $ \int_{0}^{1} f^k dx = \int_{An} f^k + \int_{[0,1]\An} f^k $ right? And since f^k is positive, thats where the inequality comes from?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The result also holds btw without assuming f nonnegative. Simply first consider $f^2$ (which is positive) to deduce that $f$  must a.e take values in $\{-1,0,1\}$ and then use $\int f=\int f^2$ to conclude.

Comment: I see, thanks. One more question though, how would I know that the set of points for which f(x)=0 or 1 almost everywhere would be measurable though? Is this because the set of points A' where f is bigger than 1 is has measure 0 hence measurable, and so does the set of points A'' where f is not 0 or 1, hence the set A =[0,1] - (A' U A'') is measurable? (A being the x's where f is 0 or 1.)

Comment: @Socchi $f$ is measurable. Then $\{\,x\mid f(x)=0\text{ o r}1\,\}$ is measurable as preimage of a measuerable set.